# Show that a set of matrices make up a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let V be a k-dimensional subspace of $R^n$, let $M_{nm}$ denote the set of $n × m$ -matrices, and let
$W$ be the set of $n × m$-matrices A that satisfies that Range(A) is a subspace of V .

(a) Show that W is a subspace of $M_{nm}$.

(b) Determine the dimension of W.

Usually I have something to say but in this case, I am totally lost.

Here is the answer for a. I haven't got b since I haven't done a.

"If B is a matrix with row space V ⊥ we have that a matrix A is in W precisely if $BA = 0$.
Henc W is given as the set of solutions to a homogenous linear system of equation, which
shows that it is a subspace of $M_{nm}$."

Comment: I'd say that $A$ is in $W$ precisely if any linear combination of its columns is in $V$. And since $V$ is a vector space this is precisely the case when $A$'s columns are in $V$.

Comment: To show this is a subspace, you merely have to check that a linear combination of matrices in $W$ is still in $W$, which is not so difficult. Also I believe the dimension would be something like $k \times m$. Can you prove it ?

Comment: If for all vectors $v$ we have $Mv \in A$ then you need to check that for two distinct elements of $W$ that $M_1$ and $M_2$ that $(\alpha M_1 + \beta M_2)v \in A$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ scalars. Can you see why that's true?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you think in terms of linear maps. Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and consider $L(X,Y)$, the set of linear maps $X\to Y$, endowed with its natural vector space structure.

If $V$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $Y$, we can consider
$$
W=\{f\in L(X,Y):\operatorname{Im}(f)\subseteq V\}
$$
Is $W$ a subspace? Yes, it's the same as $L(X,V)$. And its dimension is…

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, whay do you mean by $x -> y$ I thought you said x and y were vectors?

Comment: @KibMe $X\to Y$ denotes a generic linear map from the vector space $X$ to the vector space $Y$.